# jQuery, PHP - How to make a 'Get started' popup box

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create one of those pop-up boxes you'll get the first time you log in to my website. I wan't this to have some 'Get started' articles, FAQ and so one.

But I can't figure out how I would make this happen? I would like to create it in jQuery and PHP.

But should I have a row['getStarted'] in my database set to 0 or 1, and then display the popup box if it's set to 1? Or is there a better way to do it?

And I've also been looking for how to change a row in the Database, with just a simple click on a button like: "Don't show me this again". I've figured out I need ajax, but how would an action like this look like?

I hope to get some links or a way to get started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need jQuery and PHP.

*But should I have a row['getStarted'] in my database set to 0 or 1, and then display the popup box if it's set to 1?*

Yes you should do exactly that. Maybe in the 'users' table.

This is an example, I didnt test it but it should work. 

Its just to show you in 3-4 steps how its done.

---

***MySQL table -USERS***

```
id  UserID    FirstName    Popup
1   7804      Peter        1   
2   5874      Lois         0
3   9875      Joseph       1
```

---

***Html*** 
*//An element (image/button/what ever) with the class "No_popups_for_me"
 
//and a pseudo element named UserID*

//Here you can check before displaying the element if the user has popup enabled.

```
<?php
 include ("connection.php"); //Your connection settings to MySQL
 $activate = "SELECT id from users WHERE UserID='".$VARIABLE_CONTAINING_THE_USER_INFO."' AND Popup='".1."' ";
 $activate_src= mysql_query($activate);
 if (mysql_num_rows($activate_src)>0) {
 echo '<div class="No_popups_for_me" UserID="'.$VARIABLE_CONTAINING_THE_USER_INFO.'"></div>';
 }
```

?>

---

***JavaScript*** 
//*User clicks the button to disable popups*.

```
$('.No_popups_for_me').click(function(){
jQuery.ajax
({
  type: "POST", //method used to send data
  url: "./update_users.php", // which file to call
  data: { UID:$(this).attr('UserID') }, //Grab UserID from the html element, store it in a var named UID
  cache: false
}
});
```

---

***PHP***
*// file update_users.php*

```
<?php
 include ("connection.php"); //Your connection settings to MySQL
 $current_user = intval(trim($_POST['UID'])); //Get the data ajax send via post
 $disable_popup="UPDATE users set Popup=0 WHERE id=$current_user"; //Update SQL
 mysql_query($disable_popup) or die ("Error10.25");
?>
```

Comment: What is the data: { UID:USER_ID } all about? How does the brackets and all do? A bit of explanation here :)

Comment: Ahh, nice one. I'll try this - but I do like the bootstrap modal thing. But having troubles setting it up.

Comment: How would I check if the row is 0 or 1? Should I have a database call on the index page all the time?

Comment: Yes, but should I be doing like this: select popup from users where userid=1.. and then check if the popup=1 show the popup everytime on the index? I just thought that was bad performance.

Comment: This is just an example.  You can do the optimization :)

Answer (score 1):

What I will do, is to have a "last_login" attribute in the user table. 
if row["last_login"] is NULL, then it's first time login. 
if it is a timestamp, then it is not the first time. 
And obviously you need to update this attribute every time the user login.

The other reason for me to have this attribute, is to keep track of the active users.

for the AJAX, I recommend to use the Bootstrap, A css&js framework build by Twitter. 
The Modals plugin fits your needs perfectly.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Hey Greg. I do already have an lastSeen table - but when they login the first time this row is updated obviously.

Comment: I do have some troubles setting it up - how do I make the nice black background and make it as a popup?

Comment: To setup the modal, add jQuery.js and bootstrap.js to your page first. Than follow the "Markup" section in the link I provide above. And, at the end of "Markup" section, it tell you how to add the fancy fade in/out animation to your modal.

Comment: Yeah I now, but all the css is not provided or what?

Comment: oh, bootstrap comes with bootstrap.css, all basic css styles you need to build a site are provided. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html click Download

Comment: oh, nice - ill look at it. I've given you the vote up, but I have to accept the other answer, since he has helped a lot. Hope everything is fine :)